# Select id from datagrid and insert related info into another table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database

On my webpage I have two search boxes and five other text boxes for student information. A user can search the database for a student by either first name, last name, or both names upon clicking search. Then if there are multiple entries with the same name the results will be displayed in a datagrid and I have the "Select" function enabled so the user can select which student it is based on other information returned from the search.

The first and last names are held in one table (`StudentList`) from my Access database with the `studentID` as the primary key and related to the second table (`JournalEntries`) with `StudentID` being the foreign key. In the `JournalEntries` table there can be multiple journal entries per student and the columns I have are (`EntryID, StudentID, Topic, Summary, Author`).

What I want is when a user searches for a student and then selects the proper student, and when the other five textboxes are filled out and the button "Submit" is clicked, the journal entry will be added to that particular selected student into the `JournalEntries` table.

```
protected void btnSubmitJournalEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Sites\new\App_Data\new.mdb";
    string cmdstr = "insert into JournalEntries (Topic, SubTopic, Summary, Notes, Author) values (@Topic, @SubTopic, @Summary, @Notes, @Author)";

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
    con.Open();
    //The following fields are added from the journal entry form to the corresponding database fields
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Topic", ddlTopic.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTopic", txtSubTopic.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", txtSummary.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtNotes.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", txtNotesAuthor.Text)"
    con.Close();
    //End
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Journal entry has been successfully added!')", true);
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far?  If you add your markup/code, we can help guide you more easily.

Comment: How are you wanting to solve this? An event on Page 1 causes a change on Page 2, or will the event on Page 1 be written (database, text file, etc) and Page 2 will have a timer to check the set value?

Comment: I just have the insert statement for the journal entry, I don't know enough sql to know how to pull the selected value from the search and use it as reference so it goes to the proper student.

Comment: i think you should use one of the data grid event to insert the row or loop through data grid to grab the selected values that you can use.